# How to add to a chain of methods by checking if statements

Tags: c#

I don't know the right terminology for this but i have a simple C# code snippet which tweens some objects like this:

```
camera.gameObject.transform.DOMove(target,3.0f)
.SetEase(Ease.InOutQuad)
.OnComplete(animation.FadeIn);
```

But what i need to do is add another method to this chain based on a certain condition like this:

```
camera.gameObject.transform.DOMove(target,3.0f)                       
.SetEase(Ease.InOutQuad)            

  //the general idea
  if(visible == true){
  .OnStart(animation.FadeOut);
  }         

.OnComplete(animation.FadeIn);
```

Obviously this is a syntax error, but i do not know the correct way to handle something like this for the syntax.

How should i approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to place the entire chunk in your `if`-`else` statement, you cannot break it down:

```
if(visible == true){
  camera.gameObject.transform.DOMove(target,3.0f)                   
.SetEase(Ease.InOutQuad) .OnStart(animation.FadeOut).OnComplete(animation.FadeIn);
  }      
else {
  camera.gameObject.transform.DOMove(target,3.0f)                   
.SetEase(Ease.InOutQuad).OnComplete(animation.FadeIn);      
}
```

Alertnatively:

```
var intermediateObject = camera.gameObject.transform.DOMove(target,3.0f)                   
    .SetEase(Ease.InOutQuad);

if (visible) {
    intermediateObject.OnStart(animation.FadeOut).OnComplete(animation.FadeIn);;
}
else {
    intermediateObject.OnComplete(animation.FadeIn);;
}
```

The `var` keyword means that you do not need to worry about the type of the object yourself, but then again, its usage does hinder readability (in my opinion).

Comment: Yeah i can see how that will get messy as i add more things. If i convert to object - would i need to convert it back? How would i know what type to convert it back to.

Comment: @WDUK: You would need to see whatever it is that your objects are returning. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Ah it seems i do not need to convert it back to its original type anyway which is very handy! Thanks - this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep everything in one chain you can try using `If` extension:

```
internal static T If<T> (this T source, bool isTrue, Action<T> thenAction) {
    if (isTrue) {
        thenAction(source);
    }
    return source;
}
```

This extension will work if `OnStart` returns same `camera` object. Otherwise, `If` extension should be changed.

Then your code would look like this:

```
camera.gameObject.transform.DOMove(target,3.0f).
    SetEase(Ease.InOutQuad)
    If(visible == true, value => value.OnStart(animation.FadeOut)).
    OnComplete(animation.FadeIn)
```

If `OnStart` actually returns different `object`:

```
internal static T If<T> (this T source, bool isTrue, Func<T, T> thenFunction) =>
    isTrue ? thenFunction(source) : source;
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but the signature of your `If` is wrong. The `Action<T> thenAction` parameter should be `Func<T, T> thenAction`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Depends. If it is the same `object`, then you don't actually need to return it. That's why I wrote comment: "This extension will work if OnStart returns same camera object." If `OnStart` actually returns different `object`, then whole definition should be changed to `<TSource, TResult>`

Comment: You should always assume that the builder returns a new reference. Builders that return `this` are a lazy programming practice. Also the types can't be `<TSource, TResult>` unless there is also an "else" option.